# How can I adapt the display of my website to different window sizes?

Tags: sass, angular9, bootstrap-5, scss-mixins

Is there a solution to adapt the display of my website to the different sizes of the navigation windows?
here is an example of the desired solution: https://www.burckhardtpartner.com/de/projekte/

Comment: This question can not really be answered until you provide some of your markup

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Require more details to provide a solution

Answer (score 0):

A bit generic question, however a basic strategy is:

1. Give every item one/third of the width, using calc() to include the margins – Ex. width: `calc(33.33% - 15px)`
2. Establish Media Queries with a modified width according to Tablet or Mobile Viewport  –  Ex. `@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) { .column { width: 50% }  }`